# Lights Out game over GF(p)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorial-game-theory, tiling

On Jaap's Puzzle Page

```
   http:// www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/lomath.htm#domtilings
```

Theorem 7 says:

If standard Lights Out is played on a m x n grid-like board, then all light patterns on that board are solvable iff the number of ways to tile the board with dominoes and monominoes is odd .

Of course, here Lights Out is over two elements field GF(2) . Guestion is - what about Lights Out over GF(p) with p prime number. Very intriguing question to me: find the answer on complete solvability on m x n rectangular board over GF(p) in terms of number of tilings board with some tiles, possibly coloured .

Comment: Rules for lights out over GF(p) are the same as over GF(2). You choose any cell and add to its and to its neighbours any integer modulo p. The purpose of the game is starting with given configuration to obtain all zeroes grid

Comment: There is some discussion at http://www.slideshare.net/PengfeiLi1/lop-38272545 and also http://www.iespravia.com/rafa/luces/Lights.pdf

Comment: http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/lomath.htm seems to be a clearinghouse for stuff about variations of Lights Out.

Comment: Yes, there are discussions and articles using linear algebra. The question is whether there is some way to characterise solvability in terms of tiling using dominoes and monominoes as in quoted Theorem 7 for game over GF(2)

Comment: I don't know. Have you looked at all the links I have posted? If so, you should list in the body of your question all the sites you've looked at, so people don't waste their time telling you things you already know. And if you haven't looked at all these links, well, what are you waiting for? Here's another one: http://www.units.miamioh.edu/sumsri/sumj/2001/GraphTheory2001.pdf

Comment: There are  NO publications concerning the complete solvability of the game with other p except 2 in terms of TILING the board.

Comment: A recent paper dealing with complete solvability with $p$ other than 2 is Martin Kreh, "Lights Out" and variants, Amer Math Monthly 124 (December 2017) 937-950 (but I don't think tiling comes up).

Answer (score 2):

It might be of interest to you:

Hunziker, Machiavelo and Park prove that there are
infinitely many square grids which are not completely solvable for
$p = 3$ and formulate a conjecture  which  would  prove  the  result  true  for  all  primes. Here is the link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.394.7187&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Maithreya